# How to get url Cloudfront CDN in Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, storage, amazon-cloudfront

I am using `FileStorage` from Laravel to store uploaded files. To get the url of a file I am using:

```
$url = Storage::url('/test/image.jpg');
```

It does return the url of the file on Amazon S3, however I want it to return the url of the file on CDN CloudFront.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Set url to your cloudfront url in config/filesystems/s3

```
's3' => [
    'driver' => 's3',
    'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
    'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
    'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    'url' => 'http://xxx.cloudfront.net'
]
```